# What's the difference between the jira-rest-java-api and jira-rest-api tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [jira-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-api) is well described:

> JIRA REST APIs are for developers who want to integrate JIRA with other standalone or web applications, and administrators who want to script interactions with the JIRA server.

Currently there are 322 questions with that tag.

Unfortunately there is no description of [jira-rest-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-java-api).

Currently there are 7 questions with that tag and 3 of them are also tagged with [jira-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-api).

Is there anybody, who can explain the difference?

Comment: I don't actually know, but looking at it, a quick guess: It looks like jira-rest-api is used with more languages than just java. It _could_ be that someone wanted a tag for _just_ the api as used in java, but that's rather pointless (and if that's the case, it's being misused anyway.) Once again, this is just a guess. A user of the api could probably give a more definitive answer on if the second tag has a point or not.

Comment: It might be they are talking about the client that consumes the API with the _jira-rest-java-api_. While it's true that Jira and thus its API is a Java program, I don't think that should be relevant for the tag of a question about it here, as there are no other server implementations in different languages. If they mean client, they can tag _java_ and something for api client as well.

Answer (score 7):

The jira rest API is universal. There isn't a special one just for Java as far as I am aware. Some people are just tagging it wrong I would say, they should be two separate tags. E.g. jira-rest-api and java

Answer (score 2):

The [jira-rest-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-java-api) is supposed to be about a Java client library that wraps the Jira REST API. I can imagine it to be about [REST Java Client for JIRA | Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client/server/overview), for example.

That being said, from a few clicks through the questions in that tag, most are tagged incorrectly with that tag, as they're about using the [jira-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-api) using a Java HTTP client (hand-crafting REST requests) or even from JavaScript.